# Pairing bluetooth mobile device and send data to windows application using c++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, bluetooth, winsock

I am still new to c++ and winsock stuff. I want to make a MFC application in c++ language with functionality of connecting to a mobile device and transfer data between the PC and mobile device. I cannot find much information on the internet regarding this topic, or maybe is because I am too new this c++ and MFC application, thus having trouble implementing these libraries. I want to start from scanning and discovering nearby Bluetooth devices in an empty c++ console application. Previously done it in c# using the 32Feet.Net library. Do suggest me on how I can perform such task by using c++. Thanks for viewing this topic.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedevice

Comment: I have created a client code and server code and they can build in my pc without error. By using the client.cpp code, my pc is able to pair with my phone, with the PIN request shown, but after that my phone didnt receive any message from my pc although on the console it stated that the message has been sent. Is there any android mobile application that supports RFCOMM Serial Port Profile communication available on the google play store? Below is my client and server code, feel free to have a look.[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sIUsSXGf0ipK5bKLsi4_Gm3GIcoDmEm4?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cajax.gps2bt2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.